# MS Access SQL IN Clause cannot write to database

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have recently re-written the VBA code in an inherited database, to include the IN statement to connect to the database, rather than have linked tables constantly connected (close to 400 users will have the front-end open at any one time, so it makes attempting to access the database to make design changes near on impossible).

However, reading from the database using the IN clause works just fine, but using them on a write statement seems to execute in VBA just fine, but not actually make any changes to the database.

The statement not writing is here:

```
CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE [PS_DB] " & _
                " IN '' [MS Access;PWD=*passwd string here*;DATABASE=I:\*filepath here*\PM_DB_testenvironment.accdb] " & _
                " SET [PS_DeleteTS]= '" & Format(Now, "dd/mm/yy hh:mm") & " - " & usernm & "'" & _
                " WHERE PS_DB.PS_TeamName = '" & tm & "' AND [PS_Delete]= TRUE; "
```

Removing the IN clause, and executing the statement, writes to the database just fine.

Is it possible I need to set the read/write status of the database here?

Comment: >400 users with an `Ms Access` backend would be a nightmare to me. This is a task for a `RDBMS`. (`MSSQL Server`, `MySQL`,`Postgre`, etc ...) and will solve most of your problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `CurrentDb` to execute queries on another Access database is a bad practice.

Open up a connection to that database instead:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = DBEngine(0).OpenDatabase("I:\*filepath here*\PM_DB_testenvironment.accdb", False, False, "MS Access;PWD=*passwd string here*")
db.Execute "your query", dbFailOnError
db.Close
```

Comment: Thanks @Erik - is the main benefit to this to prevent SQL injection and strings breaking with apostrophes?

Comment: @RazorKillBen Nope, there are many, such as having control of when the connection gets opened or closed (Access can reuse a read-only connection when it sees fit, or close and reopen connections when not needed, now you have control), separating `IN` logic from the rest of your query making debugging easier, and making sure your query is executed in the correct scope (an `IN` query uses other objects from the local database, while when executing it locally on an external database using DAO uses only remote objects).

Comment: Really useful - thanks again @Erik. Unfortunately, this method returns a Run-time error '3055' - Not a valid file name. MSDN suggests it's doesn't follow the naming conventions of my operating system. I'm not sure why, but am keen to use this solution over the other.

Comment: Oh, silly me, I hadn't removed the `DATABASE=` when copy-pasting. That shouldn't be there.

Comment: Not at all, thanks @Erik - this has changed everything for me!